# Flask blueprint url not found

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to create a flask app using blueprints, so I have this structure:

```
myapp/
    __init__.py
    static/
    templates/
        site/
            index.html
            register.html
        layout.html
    views/
        __init__.py
        site.py
    models.py
```

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from .views.site import site

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(site)
```

**views/site.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

site = Blueprint('site', __name__)

site.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('site/index.html')

site.route('/register/')
def register():
    return render_template('site/register.html')
```

When I run the app, and try to go to any of the routes I have, the only thing I gest is a "404 Not Found" and I don't really know what I'm doing wrong, because I'm doing exactly what this book says: [Explore Flask - Blueprints](http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/blueprints.html)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the urls you are trying to access exactly ?

Comment: @jobou when I execute it: "127.0.0.1:5000/register" for example, or just the simple home page "127.0.0.1:5000"

Answer (score 3):

You have to prepend `@` to  `site.route` like the following.

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

site = Blueprint('site', __name__)

@site.route('/')
def index():
return render_template('site/index.html')

@site.route('/register/')
def register():
    return render_template('site/register.html')
```

Comment: :) good catch. It did not stick out for me when I reviewed the code.

Comment: Oh! for god's sake!!! I'm so sleepy and tired that I forgot it was a decorator ._.